# Retrofit2 proguard occur: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void retrofit2.Callback.onResponse(retrofit2.Call, retrofit2.Response)"

Tags: java, android, gradle, retrofit2, android-proguard

I am developing a custom module project, and there is a manager class(call "**ManagerClass**" below) in it as the main entrance of this module. In this class I use retrofit2 to connect http API with enqueue mode.

> Now, what makes me crazy is that, in Debug buildType, the whole module is running faultlessly！But if I want to make JAR, it means in release mode, I want the module to be mixed and the exception occured!

This is my API method:

```
public void apiGetPublicIpInfo2(Callback<TestIp> callback) {
    Call<TestIp> call = apiService.getPublicIpInfo("http://ipinfo.io/json");
    call.enqueue(callback);
}
```

This is my usage in ManagerClass:

```
mApiManager.apiGetPublicIpInfo2(new Callback<TestIp>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TestIp> call, Response<TestIp> response) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TestIp> call, Throwable t) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

But if I create JAR, it becomes look like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG1js.jpg)

> The abstract method **onResponse** and **onFailure** of retrofit2.Callback are mixed!

The result is：

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void retrofit2.Callback.onResponse(retrofit2.Call, retrofit2.Response)"
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:809)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7377)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

The proguard-rules.pro file is normal type, just like :

```
-keep class com.----.ManagerClass {
    public <fields>;
    public <methods>;
}
```

Even I change it to

```
-keep class com.----.ManagerClass {
    *;
}
```

The override method **onResponse** and **onFailure** of anonymous inner class "**new Callback<>(){}**" are still mixed...

My module build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            jniDebuggable false
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
}
```

I don't know how to fix it after I have tried some way such as edit proguard file.

Comment: What is version of your retrofit?

Comment: The latest version "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"

Comment: can you add code of your `build.gradle` file (all dependencies)?

Comment: I've updated the question just now. Thanks for your paying attention to my question~

Answer (score 1):

Try to set this options:

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

For more detail settings see: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro

Comment: I've tried, but in my opinion, when I do it like you say, the exception still occurred, and the reason is the callback is still called onResponse in un-obfuscated. But my module is obfuscated, so the override method onResponse became method "a". Anyway, there is no problem when I don't obfuscate my module

Answer (score 0):

## Resolved my problem :

```
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform

# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8

# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature

# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }


-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

-dontwarn javax.annotation.GuardedBy
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
```

You need to keep your models, don't obfuscate them. I saw errors with your models, sqlite cannot work on your models. It should be like this:

```
-keep class package.to.yourmodels.** { *; }
```

Comment: I've tried. When I do it like you say, the exception still occurred, and the reason is the callback is still called onResponse in un-obfuscated. But my module is obfuscated, so the override method onResponse became method "a". Anyway, as your mind, there is no problem when I don't obfuscate my module. But this is my requirement...